# Max. number of process can be in its critical section

Tags: operating-system, mutex

I just got a question at hand but the answer mentioned for it seems to be confusing.

```
Que.- Each Process Pi, i=1....9 is coded as follows
          repeat 
              P(mutex)
              {Critical section}
              V(mutex)
          forever

The code for P10 is identical except it uses v(mutex) in place of p(mutex). What is the largest number of processes that can be inside the critical section at any moment.
a) 1 b) 2 c) 3 d) None
```

I believe the answer can be 3 as any one of Pi's(i=1 to 9) can be in its CS. As soon as Processor context switch to P10, it signals a mutex and it can go to its CS along with one other process from Pi's(i=1..9)

But the answer mentioned is 2. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be 3

suppose mutex value is 1 now if P0 is schedule then mutex = 0, and P0 comes in its CS. Now suppose context switch happens and P10 is schedule as P10 first statement is V mutex value will become 1 and P10 will be in its CS as well at this point of time 2 process P0 and P10 are in its CS  now again context switch happens and suppose P1 is schedule then it will also goes into its CS, and value of mutex = 0
now, at this point we have three process in CS P0,P1 and P10 and mutex value is 0. Now to make mutex value 1 any of this three process has to call P which means it will come out of its CS.So any moment of time max only 3 process are possible in its cs

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out in the same way. forgot to put answer here

Comment: @user2129312 if the value of mutex is 0 then p10 or any other process is not allowe to enter in CS.

Comment: p10 will have V(mutex) in both places we have misread the quetsion

Answer (score 4):

**The answer will be 10.**

Suppose initially mutex = 1. P1 enters CS and sets mutex=0; then P10 enters CS and sets mutex=1. Thereafter P1 enters CS and sets mutex=0. At this point we have 3 processes in CS. Next suppose P10 exits, so mutex=1 and P2 enters. Then again suppose P10 enters. Now we have 4 processes in CS (P0,P1,P2,P10). Again P10 exits and this process continues till the end. Finally we will have all the processes in CS.

This is under the consideration that none of the processes can be called more than once simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 2 and below is the explanation.

Initial value of mutex=1

```
case 1 - any one process among p1...p9 enters the critical section
```

The value of mutex is set to 0 by calling P() i.e it becomes zero no other process not even 10 is allowed to enter CS as mutex value is 0.

```
case 2 - process p10 enters the critical section
```

The value of mutex is not going to be changed as calling V() trys to set the value of mutex 1 which already is 1.Since the value of mutex is 1 any other process p1...p9 is allowed to enter its critical section and hence the maximum no of process at any time in CS is 2.

The key to solve the problem is that the value that a mutex can take is only 0 and 1 and no other value.

Comment: Aksam: why "The value of mutex is set to 0 by calling P() i.e it becomes zero no other process not even 10 is allowed to enter CS as mutex value is 0." P10 can enter anytime it wants, to exit however it requires a free mutex.

Answer (score -1):

I think answer should be 11 (P0,P1...P9 and P10). Let's see why am i saying this,

for P10
{
    v(mutex)
     {CS}
    V(mutex)
}

consider the situation:

P0  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=1

P10 enters        mutex unblocked                Total process=2

P1  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=3

P10 exits         mutex unblocked                Total process=2

P2  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=3

P10 enters        mutex unblocked                Total process=4

P3  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=5

P10 exits         mutex unblocked                Total process=4

P4  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=5

P10 enters        mutex unblocked                Total process=6

P5  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=7

P10 exits         mutex unblocked                Total process=6

P6  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=7

P10 enters        mutex unblocked                Total process=8

P7  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=9

P10 exits         mutex unblocked                Total process=8

P8  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=9

P10 enters        mutex unblocked                Total process=10

P9  enters        mutex blocked                  Total process=11

Comment: Start from P1 not P0.